# Order strings fields in django QuerySet by specific order

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a string field `status` that accepts 3 values

1. "ON_ITS_WAY"
2. "DELIVERED"
3. "PACKAGING"

I want to be able to sort queryset objects by the `status` field by custom deciding the order :

"DELIVERED" > "ON_ITS_WAY" > "PACKAGING"

so meaning every record with the status "DELIVERED" will appear first and so on.

haven't found a way to do it with Django :(, can anyone help?
thanks!

Comment: Alphabetical should work (D -> O -> P):`MyClass.objects.all().order_by("status")`

Comment: it was just an example.
Alphabetical doesnt work in my case

Comment: How long will the list of choices usually be?

Comment: 3 choices, but alphabetical order doesnt work. 

imagine it's 
A < C < B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's Imagine your model is called `Order`, then your queryset will look like this.

```
preference = Case(
        When(status="DELIVERED", then=Value(0)),
        When(status="ON_ITS_WAY", then=Value(1)),
        When(status="PACKAGING", then=Value(2))
)
query_set = Order.objects.alias(preference=preference).order_by('preference')
```

### Check these methods from Official Django Docs:

[When](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#when)

[Case](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case)

[alias](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#alias)

Comment: you are a king. thanks a lot!!! it worked

Comment: thanks my friend...I solved this issue a few weeks ago you are lucky that a found your question in front of me.